# Does RestSharp have an issue with "Dots" in the url

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, restsharp

I am trying to use RestSharp in a console application, to connect to an api, but in the response, I keep getting "Unable to connect to remote server".

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=foo&password=bar");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
```

I basically expect RestSharp to call the following:

```
finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=???&password=???
```

This works for me in postman and in the browser, but not in restsharp. I have tested with other url inside the console application and it works.

I do not usually have any issues with restSharp, so I am considering if it is the "Dot" between Api.mvc inside the URL?

Comment: No, it does not have issues with a `.` or any other symbol as long as the URL is correct. As mentioned in the other thread, it's likely a firewall or proxy that would block your application but not Postman etc. You have not stated any details about your network setup.

Comment: Out of interest, anyone else reading these comments, can you indicate if `https://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1` is a valid URL for you? OP says it works for him (as stated), I get a timeout every time on an unfiltered internet connection.

Comment: have you tried the url, because it works for me.
please try the url in the question.
    https://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=foo&password=bar

Comment: @Equalsk I just accessed the url from my browser... `Authenticate` is the first method displayed and it has `Requires authentication: False`

Comment: Don't know what changed but that URL now works for me. Definitely did not before, I can guarantee I tried it several times.

Comment: @Equalsk same here.. also `https://finans-dk.pronestor.com/Api.mvc/v1/Authenticate?login=MyLogin&password=MyPassword` gives the `Invalid username or password` response so basically a successful response... also In the first thread the url was called in the RestSharp client with a http protocol.. does it affect the connection? cause with https seems to be okay

Comment: Now that the URL is actually working for me I can guarantee that the code I showed as the answer in the other thread works perfectly and returns a `200 - OK`. The issue is with your setup blocking your application.

Comment: @Equalsk it actually might have been something weird on my end, and I apologize.
I restarted the computer and now the above works.
I then tried the code from the previous post and that still does not work.

Comment: @Noel Yes there would be a difference between `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. I did try both and got the same issue, but have corrected my code to reflect that it should be `HTTPS`. It's clear that OP has tried `HTTPS` so that's not the error.

Comment: It's because I'd copied your URL as `HTTP` and not `HTTPS` which I have now corrected. Try again with `HTTPS`.

Comment: @Equalsk that is it!!!! thank you! you are golden!

Comment: Told you so ;-)